# rails-4 devise + user controller edit route redirecting to the wrong place

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

I am using devise gem in my app and a custom user controller. I have links to **edit a user** in both the show and index page. After signing in, if I click the edit link in users/index.html.erb or users/edit.html.erb, it redirects to user new form even though a GET request was sent.

In the route, I am skipping registrable because I am using the User controller to handle that and it works fine.

this is the route

```
devise_for :users, :path_prefix => 'd', skip: [:registrations], controllers: {sessons: "sessions"}
resources :users
```

**rake routes | grep edit_user** gives

```
  edit_user_password GET    /d/users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit                                                                
  edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)        users#edit
```

users/show.html.erb

```
 <div class="btn btn-primary"> <%= link_to "Edit", edit_user_path(@user) %></div>
```

This is the screenshot of the registration form that comes up when I click on the edit link in either the index or show page. It is making a get request but displaying the form for new instead of form for edit.

[image]

**The is the log from clicking the edit link in the show page:**

```
  Started GET "/users/17/edit" for at 2013-08-19 08:40:49 +0000                                                                       
    Processing by UsersController#edit as HTML                                                                                                        
    Parameters: {"id"=>"17"}                                                                                                                        
    User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "17"]]                                                 
    User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 17 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1                                      
    Rendered users/_form.html.erb (17.5ms)                                                                                                          
    Rendered users/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (26.8ms)                                                                                
    Completed 200 OK in 50ms (Views: 47.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms
```

The users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
   before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:new, :create]
   respond_to :html, :json

   def show
   end

   def edit
   end

   private

   def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
   end

 end
```

users/_edit.html.erb **I even specified url path in the form and it still renders new form**

```
 form_for(@user, :url => edit_user_path(@user))
```

users/edit.html.erb

```
  <%= render "edit" %>
```

users/index.html.erb

```
 <% @users.each do |user| %>

  <div class="btn btn-primary"><%= link_to "Edit", edit_user_path(user) %> </div>
  <div class="btn btn-danger"><%= link_to 'Remove', user, method: :delete, data:    {confirmation: 'Are you sure'} %></div>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are making a POST request to the edit user path whereas this path is registered with the GET method. That's why you get this error.

Personally, instead of skipping the registration, I would have overwritten the registrations controller as described in the Devise wiki.

Comment: Thanks Justin. the error says is a POST request, but when I do **rake routes | grep edit_user** it shows what the route generates is a GET request. So the response from the grep is **edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format) users#edit** So I really don't know at what point it switches itself into a POST request.

Comment: When you call `button_to`, it will generate a POST link.

Comment: Thanks @sevenseacat. I just went back my user/show.edit.erb and I had changed the links yesterday to this <%= link_to "Edit", edit_user_path(@user) %>

Comment: and that wont cause such a problem.

Comment: Thanks @sevenseacat, see the updated cleaner stack trace and the edit link no longer makes a post request, how it still displays the form for new even after making a GET request.

Comment: Your new and edit pages are using the same form, as far as I can see.

Comment: thanks. It is a form partial that uses since their fields are thesame. I have other models like product, order etc that also uses form partial to share a common base form between new and edit and those work well. Just this user model that is acting wrongly.